# Polymer 1.0 how can I style a paper-input:disabled?

Tags: css, polymer, material-design, web-component

Polymer 1.0 question:

When a paper-input is set to 'disabled', the text and underline turn to a really light gray that is hard to read.  How can I set the text color using css.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
--paper-input-container-input-disabled {
    color:black;
}

<paper-input label="Email" disabled></paper-input>
```

But it doesn't change the text color.  Although I can change the background color using the same mixin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [online document](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) lists the name wrong. It should be `--paper-input-container-disabled`. So this would work -

```
paper-input {
  --paper-input-container-disabled: {
    opacity: 0.66;
  };
}
```

Note the default `opacity` is `0.33`. So maybe increase it a bit to make it clearer.